In SageMath, how to put group element into standard form
Here's some simple code showing my problem
G = groups.presentation.Cyclic(7)
q = G[1]
w = G[5]
print(f"{q} * {w} = {q*w}")
for x in G: print(x)

This shows q*w as a^4 but iterating the group elements you don't get this element because in the group it is represented as a^-3. How can I get the a^4 into this equivalent form?

OK, I have found that I can do it with the following code
print(G[G.list().index(q*w)])

This will print a^-3 rather than a^4.
But is there an more efficient way?
